# MySQL think I need to use ROLLUP but i'm not sure

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

If i has a group of people identifiers (12,34,54,65) and a database with Keys (Gender, Age, Salary for example), such as:

Details table

```
{Person ID,   Key,    Value}
{12,           Gender,  Male}
{34,           Age,     40}
{54,           Salary,  30000}
```

Personnel table

```
ID
12
34
54
65
```

I want to create rows consisting of the powerset of `{12,34,54,65} x {Age,Salary,Gender}`, regardless of whether there is a data value in the Details table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need rollup, you need to pivot table -

```
SELECT p.id, d.gender, d.age, d.salary FROM personnel p
  JOIN (
    SELECT person_id,
      MAX(IF(`key` = 'gender', `value`, NULL)) AS gender,
      MAX(IF(`key` = 'age', `value`, NULL)) AS age,
      MAX(IF(`key` = 'Salary', `value`, NULL)) AS salary
    FROM
      details
    GROUP BY
      person_id) d
    ON p.id = d.person_id;
```

Comment: Does it matter that gender, age and salary are not actually table columns in details? The columns are 'Person ID', 'Key' and 'Value' ?

Comment: @Devart... Why the MAX's? It appears to me that the IF's can only ever return a singleton... are you just forcing the query parser to accept that fact? Would `FIRST 1` do the same? Can even you use first in sub-selects? Sorry to be a pain... just interested. Cheers. Keith.

Comment: @James. The inner sub select creates a temporary table with the columns gender,age and salary so no it doesn't matter. Also the join needs to be a LEFT JOIN if you want to see rows for people who don't have any information in the details table, like id 65 in the example data above.

Comment: @corlettk It is a pivot table pattern, there is no special command like in MS SQL, and it is like a trick. About the MAX - there could be another function (for example - SUM), this function helps us to find out a value within group, ...and there should not be the same rows in details table;)

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you're looking for is plain old:

```
select * from personnel p, details d where d.person_id = p.person_id
```

But that `details` table smells like a fundamentally broken design to me. What type is the `value` column? A string? and it's storing strings, integers, and currency values? Good luck with that. I hope you don't want to actually USE any of this data, let alone search on it.

**EDIT:** Nope... I now think Devart is spot-on. I didn't understand the question. Sigh.